# Why am I seeing <!-- ... --> in the HTTP Referer field?

Tags: http, xss, pcap, http-referer, snort

I'm running a Snort IDS and one of the rules matches on `<!--{1,200}-->` in the `Referer` field in the HTTP header. When I look at the pcap there doesn't seem to be any consistency. Sometimes it looks like HTML. In one case there was `<!--SS_END_SNIPPET (2,17)-->` (or something like that).

I've searched Google, on here, and have yet to find anything that explains this, and I can't figure out what the purpose might be.

The signature came in a set. If I can refine it to capture what it is supposed to be looking for I'd like to change it. It generates a lot of matches. Or maybe I'd like to eliminate it completely.

What is the purpose of this, and what does it have to do with cross site scripting?

Comment: Can you post the actual signature? Can you also provide the actual full http referer?

Comment: Sure. It's just the regex I posted: <!--.{1,200}-->

Comment: Sure. It's just the regex I posted: <!--.{1,200}-->
And here's an example of a referer:

`http://www/factmonster.com/ipka/A0908763.html East Timor <--ao--><hr><BR>More questions and answers...<br><li><a href=`

It ends just like that.

Here's another:

`http://finance.yahoo.com/q?s=<!--dnr=-->`

I know it's not something to be concerned about. I'm just curious what's going on with the use of that.